# Lag length selection in a VAR model: information criteria favour zero lag

Tags: model-selection, vector-autoregression, lags

[image]

I want to study the impulse response function and the variance decomposition by fitting a VAR model. The lag length criteria gave me this result. What's the problem?

Comment: Your model is miss-specified if it includes lag 0. If the 0 is in fact the first lag, then there is no problem, just pick the lag that has highest value according to some criterion (that would be one lag). Remember that this procedure assumes same data also.

Comment: I don't get your answer. How can a model be miss-specified I didn't estimate the model. I'm seeking for the optimal lag to fit a lag model.

I have 4 stationnary. I made them stationnary

ps: I'm using eviews

Comment: @Dole, 0 lag may mean no lags, not inclusion of the zero lag.

Comment: Yes, it means that the optimal lag is zero. What could be the cause of such a result?

Comment: @user109464 That would mean mere constant maximizes the criterion, since none of the VAR model should be left. Again, VAR model can't be estimated with 0 lags, so I hope you have correct specification (IE 1 = first lag, 2 = first and 2nd lag etc.) No contemporaneous terms should be allowed.

Comment: So how can I choose the optimal lag ?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the criteria (lowest AIC, lowest BIC, etc.), zero lag is preferred, which means a model with just an intercept but no lags. From such a model you will not be able to obtain impulse response functions, while variance decomposition will be trivial (none of the variables explains the variance). The selection of zero lag suggests that VAR might not be a good model for your data, so you might want to explore alternative models.

Answer (score -1):

If zero lag presents mean there is no contribution of past value of the exogenous variable. So it is not a time series problem It is simple regression